# Operative Definitions of Memory in Circuits

Tags: memory, theory, non-volatile-memory, memristor

I've been studying Memristors (non-ideal) and some related circuits depending on pinched hysteresis of the IV for use in memory. I'm still puzzled by the lack of general framework for what constitutes memory and what features one needs to use a circuit as a memory volatile or non volatile.

It seems you certainly need some nonlinearity that is preserves history of input as in hysteresis (effectively non-locality of physical quantities such as Current or Voltage). For example recently I found out one of the criterion set by a well cited article is merely a mathematical constraint and has nothing to do with practical purposes or use for memory or engineering purposes of the circuit.

What is an operative definition of memory in circuits and what framework is used in defining such memory and protocols for reading and writing information at the circuit level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I'm wondering if anyone is aware...* - this isn't really a valid question because someone, somewhere will be aware hence, the answer is "yes". Also, requests for information and where to find them is basically shopping and the site rules state this about shopping questions: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for pointing that out, I will edit the question to be more explicit and state a question not as vague.

Comment: You don't need nonlinearity. Consider a capacitor. They're great storage elements (DRAM) but they're also linear.

Comment: Please quote the article you were reading, I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that there must be some sort of formal, mathematically consistent definition of memory.

Consider that a piece of cardboard with holes punched in it is memory. Electrical connections that are either completed or left open are memory. A mechanical switch can be memory.

Memory is whatever engineers find useful to store information. Creating an arbitrary "framework" to define it, or the protocols to access it, would constrain innovation.